# Can't start unicorn in production - can't convert Pathname into String (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I have a Rails 3 (Spree) application that I can start in development but not production.

If I run `bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -D -E development` everything works.

However, `bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -D -E production`, returns with:

`master failed to start, check stderr log for details`

Here's the unicorn.stder.log file:

```
I, [2012-06-04T17:31:54.497851 #10431]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/tmp/unicorn-uspatriottactical.socket fd=5
I, [2012-06-04T17:31:54.499222 #10431]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require': can't convert Pathname into String (TypeError)
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/spree_related_products-72cbbfc9ed31/lib/spree_related_products.rb:17:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/releases/20120604171150/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from config.ru:4:in `require'
        from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from config.ru:1:in `new'
        from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:696:in `call'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:696:in `build_app!'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:136:in `start'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/bin/unicorn:121:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        from /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Because this seems like a gem issue, here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'active_shipping',                  :git => 'git://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping.git'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'spree',                            :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree', :branch => '1-1-stable'
gem 'spree_active_shipping',            :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_active_shipping.git'
gem 'spree_flexi_variants',             :git => 'git://github.com/jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants.git'
gem 'spree_reviews',                    :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_reviews.git'
gem 'spree_related_products',           :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_related_products.git'
gem 'spree_shipworks_api',              :path => 'spree_shipworks_api'
gem 'spree_amazon_fps',                 :path => 'spree_amazon_fps'
# gem 'spree_variant_options',            :git => 'git://github.com/citrus/spree_variant_options.git'
gem 'spree_videos',                     :git => 'git://github.com/iloveitaly/Spree-Videos.git'
gem 'spree_gateway',                    :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git'
gem 'spree_paypal_express',             :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_paypal_express.git'
gem 'remit',                            :git => 'git://github.com/tylerhunt/remit.git'
#gem 'remit',                            :path => '../remit'
gem 'unicorn'

# temporary
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'


group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.0'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.4'
end

group :console do
  gem 'awesome_print',                  :require => 'ap'
  gem 'hirb-unicode'
  gem 'wirb'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 1.3.1'
  gem 'progress_bar', '0.4.0'
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
  gem "sunspot_with_kaminari", '~> 0.1'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'debugger'
end

group :development do
#  gem 'heroku'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :production do

    gem 'capistrano'
    gem 'rvm-capistrano'


    gem 'mysql2'

    gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 1.3.1'
    gem 'progress_bar', '0.4.0'
    gem 'sunspot_solr'
    gem "sunspot_with_kaminari", '~> 0.1'
end

# Used when running on Heroku
# group :deployment do
#   gem 'foreman'
#   gem 'pg'
#   gem 'thin'
# end

group :test do
  gem 'fakeweb'
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', '~> 0.8.3',               :require => false
  gem 'vcr'
end
```

Edit: here's my unicorn.rb

```
# See http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html for complete documentation.

www_dir = "/var/rails/"
app_name = "uspatriottactical"

# Set environment to development unless something else is specified
#env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "production"

# amount of unicorn workers to spin up
worker_processes 2

# Socket to bind to
listen "/tmp/unicorn-#{app_name}.socket"

preload_app true

# restarts workers that hang for 30 seconds
timeout 30

pid "/tmp/unicorn.#{app_name}.pid"



#if env == "production"
  user 'app_user', 'app_user' # 'user', 'group'

  working_directory "#{www_dir}#{app_name}/current"
  shared_path = "#{www_dir}#{app_name}/shared"

  stderr_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
  stdout_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
#end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is highly recomended for Rails + "preload_app true"
  # as there's no need for the master process to hold a connection
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  # When sent a USR2, Unicorn will suffix its pidfile with .oldbin and
  # immediately start loading up a new version of itself (loaded with a new
  # version of our app). When this new Unicorn is completely loaded
  # it will begin spawning workers. The first worker spawned will check to
  # see if an .oldbin pidfile exists. If so, this means we've just booted up
  # a new Unicorn and need to tell the old one that it can now die. To do so
  # we send it a QUIT.
  #
  # This enables 0 downtime deploys.
  old_pid = "/var/run/unicorn-#{app_name}.pid.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  # Unicorn master loads the app then forks off workers - because of the way
  # Unix forking works, we need to make sure we aren't using any of the parent's
  # sockets, e.g. db connection (since "preload_app true")
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

  # if preload_app is true, then you may also want to check and
  # restart any other shared sockets/descriptors such as Memcached,
  # and Redis.  TokyoCabinet file handles are safe to reuse
  # between any number of forked children (assuming your kernel
  # correctly implements pread()/pwrite() system calls)
end
```

Edit: Per request /var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb

I commented on line 63

```
require 'pathname'

module Polyglot
  @registrations ||= {} # Guard against reloading
  @loaded ||= {}

  class PolyglotLoadError < LoadError; end

  class NestedLoadError < LoadError
    def initialize le
      @le = le
    end
    def reraise
      raise @le
    end
  end

  def self.register(extension, klass)
    extension = [extension] unless Array === extension
    extension.each{|e|
      @registrations[e] = klass
    }
  end

  def self.find(file, *options, &block)
    is_absolute = Pathname.new(file).absolute?
    (is_absolute ? [""] : $:).each{|lib|
      base = is_absolute ? "" : lib+File::SEPARATOR
      # In Windows, repeated SEPARATOR chars have a special meaning, avoid adding them
      matches = Dir["#{base}#{file}{,.#{@registrations.keys*',.'}}"]
      # Revisit: Should we do more do if more than one candidate found?
      $stderr.puts "Polyglot: found more than one candidate for #{file}: #{matches*", "}" if matches.size > 1
      if path = matches[0]
        return [ path, @registrations[path.gsub(/.*\./,'')]]
      end
    }
    return nil
  end

  def self.load(*a, &b)
    file = a[0].to_str
    return if @loaded[file] # Check for $: changes or file time changes and reload?
    begin
      source_file, loader = Polyglot.find(file, *a[1..-1], &b)
      if (loader)
        begin
          loader.load(source_file)
          @loaded[file] = true
        rescue LoadError => e
          raise Polyglot::NestedLoadError.new(e)
        end
      else
        raise PolyglotLoadError.new("Failed to load #{file} using extensions #{(@registrations.keys+["rb"]).sort*", "}")
      end
    end
  end
end

module Kernel
  alias polyglot_original_require require

  def require(*a, &b)
    polyglot_original_require(*a, &b) # <- line 63
  rescue LoadError => load_error
    begin
      Polyglot.load(*a, &b)
    rescue Polyglot::NestedLoadError => e
      e.reraise
    rescue LoadError
      # Raise the original exception, possibly a MissingSourceFile with a path
      raise load_error
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: show your `/var/rails/uspatriottactical/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb` line 63

Comment: I added the file you requested. Thanks for the response, fl00r.

Comment: seems like this might be related: https://github.com/cjheath/polyglot/issues/2

Comment: Per the related issue link, it seems it is in fact an issue with ruby 1.9.1 and 1.9.2. Upgrading to ruby 1.9.3 seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to ruby 1.9.3 corrects this issue.

See [github.com/cjheath/polyglot/issues/2](https://github.com/cjheath/polyglot/issues/2) for details.

Apparently there is an issue with ruby 1.9.1 and 1.9.2 that RVM installs.